# How to print mat-accordion panels content with window.print?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a need to print mat-accordion panel content at the time of window.print in an Angular (6) application.

The problem is all the collapsed panels content are not visible while doing window.print.

Is there any way which I can use at @media print to fulfill my needs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Hope this helps to someone.

```
@media print{
    ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-content
  {
    overflow: visible !important;
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    height: inherit !important;
  }
}
```

You can use this globally or individually at your component level to open all the collapsible panels at the time of printing your form.